# How to delete one row using resource routes?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to delete one row from database but I am getting an error. Here's my code. How to delete that?

```
Route::resource('x', 'xController', ['only' => [
    'index', 'store', 'destroy'
]]);

<a href="{{ action('xController@destroy', $x->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>

MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing),

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

> HTML forms do not support `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` actions. So, when defining `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden `_method` field to the form. The value sent with the `_method` field will be used as the HTTP request method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a form with `DELETE` method since you're using resource controller.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('xController@destroy', $x->id) }}">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```